# CSS for SELECT element

Tags: html, css, select

I am currently trying to properly CSS style a SELECT element.

Specifically, what I want to do is to have the initial selected value be a bit distanced from the arrow/select/icon/whatever that opens the list of options.

Currently, it appears as: VALUE[V] where [V] is the triangle/arrow button. I want to create a spacing between the end of VALUE, whatever that comes to be, and the [V] button/part of the select element. Margin is obviously not relevant and padding takes place outside of the [V] as well.

Since I have several SELECT's - is there a 'CLEAN' or 'ELEGANT' method to do this through CSS other than individually giving a width to each of these elements?

Regards
G.Campos

Comment: Ugly hack... append a `&nbsp;` to the end of the text nodes of `option` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you use padding?  It seems to do what you are after..  Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/GYyKh/1/

Comment: Ok, so the answer is to style not SELECT but rather OPTION. I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Amateur-blues I guess.
Thanks a lot for the heads up.

Comment: This doesn't work... Changing that padding amount does nothing to the space where the word in the option stops and the arrow for the dropdown begins

Comment: @Matt you are right.. it only works in firefox.  Sorry Sotkra.. I will take a look again later.. when I am off the clock ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make your select have a class so that you can call it from your css. Then do something like

```
.spacer {
    width:500px;
}
```

That will give all the elements with that class name a width that you specify